# How can I execute cleanup code in my CoroutineWorker when onStopped is final?

Tags: android-workmanager

I upgraded to WorkManager 2.1.0 and tried to use some of the Kotlin extensions including `CoroutineWorker`. My worker was extending `androidx.work.Worker` previously and it was executing cleanup code by overriding `onStopped`. Why is `onStopped` final in `CoroutineWorker`? Is there any other way for me to execute cleanup code after the `CoroutineWorker` is stopped?

According to [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-meets-kotlin-b9ad02f7405e), is this supposed to be a feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always use `job.invokeOnCompletion` without having to rely on the `onStopped` callback for `CoroutineWorker`. E.g.,

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import kotlinx.coroutines.CancellationException
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope

class TestWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "TestWorker"
    }

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return coroutineScope {
            val job = async {
                someWork()
            }

            job.invokeOnCompletion { exception: Throwable? ->
                when (exception) {
                    is CancellationException -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Cleanup on completion", exception)
                        // cleanup on cancellations
                    }
                    else -> {
                        // do something else.
                    }
                }
            }

            job.await()
        }
    }

    suspend fun someWork(): Result {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Comment: Working on cancellation as well for me.

Comment: What does this mean "just use coroutineContext[Job]"? @Vlad

Comment: Can you please show some example to see how to use coroutineContext[Job]?

Comment: Really useful, Im adding this in my BaseCoroutineWorker class

Answer (score 6):

From Kotlin documentation:

> Cancellable suspending functions throw CancellationException on cancellation which can be handled in the usual way. For example, try {...} finally {...} expression and Kotlin use function execute their finalization actions normally when a coroutine is cancelled.
> [Coroutines documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#closing-resources-with-finally)

That means that you can clean up coroutine code in usual, Java/Kotlin way with try and finally:

```kotlin
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            work()
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.failure()
        } finally {
            cleanup()
        }
    }
```

Note that you can't suspend in catch and finally. If you do, use withContext(NonCancellable) [NonCancellable documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#timeout)

Answer (score 4):

Just catch `CancellationException`

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    return try {
        // here do work
        return Result.success()
    } catch (e: CancellationException) {
        // here clean up
        return Result.failure()
    }
}
```