# Android WorkManager createCancelPendingIntent() does not dismiss the notification

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-workmanager, foreground-service

I'm trying to use `WorkManager` instead of a `Foreground Service`. But I have a problem when I add `createCancelPendingIntent()`  as an Intent action for the notification. When I click "Cancel" Button in the notification, the Worker stops but the notification does not get dismissed unless I start the Worker again, wait until it's done and send another notification with the same ID but with `setOngoing(false)`.

This is my code:

```kotlin
class DownloadWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    private val notificationManager = ContextCompat
        .getSystemService(
            applicationContext,
            NotificationManager::class.java
        ) as NotificationManager

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        fakeDownload()

        notificationManager.sendNotification(
            "Download complete!",
            applicationContext)

        return Result.success()
    }

private suspend fun fakeDownload() {
       for (progress in 0..100 step 10){
            delay(1000)
            setForeground(createForeground(progress))
        }
   }

    private fun createForegroundInfo(progress: String): ForegroundInfo {
       // Pending Intent to cancel the worker
       val intent = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
               .createCancelPendingIntent(getId())

       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           createChannel()
       }

       val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, id)
           .setContentTitle("Downloading")
           .setContentText(progress)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_work_notification)
           .setOngoing(true)
           // Add the cancel action to the notification which can
           // be used to cancel the worker
           .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_delete, "Cancel", intent)
           .build()

       return ForegroundInfo(0, notification)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stopping the worker from the notification works by raising an exception. You need to catch the exception in the usual kotlin way, then manually clear the notification.

A few more details are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900141

```
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            set foreground
            do work

            Result.success()  [or failure, as applicable]
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.success()  [or failure, as applicable]
        } finally {
            clean up...

            val notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.cancelAll()    [or cancel(id) for more targetted operation]

            Log.d(tag, "finally")
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if I don't want to clear all app's notifications?